# How to use mysql_fetch_assoc to process records in php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, logic

[image]

i am trying to retrieve subject names, there are two types of subjects optional and main. Each student contains optional and main subjects. by using those subject ids i can retrieve the name from subject table.
But in this result only one optional subject name is appearing, is there any problem in my code? pls help me

```
  $subject_names = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($student_num_data);$i++)
{
    $optional_id_list = mysql_query("SELECT optional_subject_id FROM ms_student WHERE student_id = ".$student_num_data[$i]['student_id']);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($optional_id_list))
    {
        foreach ($row as $key) 
        {
            $optional_subject = mysql_query("SELECT subject_name FROM ms_subject WHERE subject_id = ".$key['optional_subject_id']); 
            $optional_subject_name = array();
            while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($optional_subject))
            {
                $optional_subject_name[] = $row1;  
            }
        }
    }
    $subject_id_list = mysql_query("SELECT subject_ids FROM subject_config WHERE stream_index =".$stu_stream);  
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($subject_id_list))
    {
        foreach ($row as $key) 
        {
            $main_subject = mysql_query("SELECT subject_name FROM ms_subject WHERE subject_id = ".$key['subject_ids']); 
            $main_subject_name = array();
            while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($main_subject))
            {
                $main_subject_name[] = $row3;  
            }
        }
    } 
    $subject_names = $main_subject_name[0]['subject_name'].','.$optional_subject_name[0]['subject_name'];

    $small_subject_name=trim($subject_names);//remove whitespace at end of string         
    $small_subject_name = str_replace(" ", "-", $small_subject_name); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.     
    $small_subject_name = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $small_subject_name); // Removes special chars.     
    $small_subject_name =  preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $small_subject_name); // Removes multiple hyphens.            
    $small_subject_name = str_replace("-", " ", $small_subject_name); // Replaces all hyphens with spaces.            
    $small_subject_name=strtolower(str_replace(" ","_",$small_subject_name));  

    if($stu_class == 11 || $stu_class == 12)
    {  
        $subject_statement = $subject_statement."IF(".$small_subject_name."='ab','ab',round(".$small_subject_name.",2)) AS ".$small_subject_name.",";   
        $sum_subject_statement = $sum_subject_statement.'IFNULL(`'.$small_subject_name.'`,0) + ';           
        /* start by 1022 02-09-2014 */
        $subject_pass_statement .= $small_subject_name." >= 33 AND ";       
        $subject_pass_statement = substr($subject_pass_statement,0,strlen($subject_pass_statement)-5);
        $update_pass_statement = "UPDATE ".$table_name." SET class_rank = 'P' WHERE 1=1 ".$track_div_stmnt.$id_stmnt." AND student_id = ".$student_num_data[$i]['student_id']." AND ".$subject_pass_statement;
        $update_pass_query=mysql_query($update_pass_statement);
    }
}
```

Comment: it's hard to follow code, especially php code - please show structure (and some data) from tables.

Comment: in table you showed us there is no column 'subject_name'...

Comment: subject_name is on another table.  ecach id have corresponding names

Comment: Install xdebug and step through the code, then paste the problematic code here.

Comment: You need to narrow down the issue and when asking for help you need to make clear what is your: 1. intention, 2. attempt to achieve it, 3. problem you encountered.

Comment: What, exactly, is your ultimate goal? Echo out a list of subjects (optional and main) for each student?

Comment: yes.. thats what im looking for

Comment: Your code uses three tables that we have no idea what the structure is and what data they contain. `ms_student`, `ms_subject`, and `subject_config`. You gave us a partial of one one table. Which table is this and what else is in this table? Next, there are variables in your code that we have no idea where or how their values were determined - `$table_name`, `$track_div_stmnt` and `$id_stmnt`. Please provide this information.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about `mysql_fetch_assoc` function, but about the logic of your code. You are having hard time, mainly because of how your code looks. You are facing too many problems at once, the most reasonable solution here is to:

### **decompose** the problem

1. Think about what are the main tasks / actions that this code will do.
   Let's say:

   1. For every student, we retrieve optional subjects they enrolled.
   2. Then we retrieve their main subjects they were taking.
   3. And then we retrieve their results to determine which subjects they have passed and which they did not.
2. Start with code that expresses your intetion, use functions that don't exist yet:

   ```
    $passStatementForYear = new PassStatement($year);
    $students = getStudentsForSchoolYear($year);
    foreach ($students as $student) {
        $optionalSubjects = loadOptionalSubjectsForStudent($student);
        $mainSubjects = loadMainSubjectsForStudent($student);
        $passReport = prepareReportForStudent(
            $student, $optionalSubjects, $mainSubjects
        );
        updatePassStatementUsingStudentsReport(
            $passStatementForYear, $passReport
        );
    }
   ```
3. Build missing parts (functions, classes etc.)

Now you just need to take care of those standalone steps. Every function introduces new small problem, which you can take care of in isolate and simple manner. Only then, if you find yourself having issues with [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php), refer to the official documentation and example they show:

```
$sql = "SELECT id as userid, fullname, userstatus
        FROM   sometable
        WHERE  userstatus = 1";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}

// While a row of data exists, put that row in $row as an associative array
// Note: If you're expecting just one row, no need to use a loop
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["userid"];
    echo $row["fullname"];
    echo $row["userstatus"];
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: when i echo the update query it returns                                                                                        UPDATE track_evaluation_11 SET class_rank = 'P' WHERE 1=1 AND evaluation_division = 'A' AND evaluation_config_id = '32' AND student_id = 1070 AND malayalam >= 33UPDATE track_evaluation_11 SET class_rank = 'P' WHERE 1=1 AND evaluation_division = 'A' AND evaluation_config_id = '32' AND student_id = 1071 AND malayalam >= 33malayalam >= 33